# how to call action from link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have index page users_controller:

```
  def index
    @companies = Company.where(:is_confirmed => "f")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @companies }
    end
  end
```

and I want at the touch of a button, the company changed the status to confirmed

```
   def confirm
    company = Company.find(params[:id])
    company.is_confirmed = "t"
    company.save
    redirect_to users_path
  end
```

button which should call confirmation

```
= link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> '.html_safe + t('Confirm'), users_path, confirm: t('Are you sure'), :controller => "users", :action => "confirm", :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success'
```

please tell me how to fix or tell me where you can see a working version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
= link_to confirm_company_path(company), confirm: 'Are you sure', method: :post do
  %i{class: "icon-ok icon-white"}
  = t('Confirm')
```

In routes.rb

```
post '/company/:id/confirm' => "users#confirm", as: :confirm_company
```

1) Don't use `GET` request when you change object, use `POST` instead.

2) Move confirm logic to company model and confirm action to companies controller

Comment: change to = link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> '.html_safe + t('Confirm'), confirm_company_path(company), confirm: t('Are you sure'), :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success' and worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose between the controller/action/id argument and the RESTful route, check the [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). You probably want this :

```
= link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> '.html_safe + t('Confirm'), :controller => "users", :action => "confirm", :id => @companies, method: :post, confirm: t('Are you sure'), :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success'
```

or

```
= link_to '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> '.html_safe + t('Confirm'), confirm_users_path(@companies), method: :post, confirm: t('Are you sure'), :class => 'btn btn-small btn-success'
```

implying your route look like this (RESTful):

```
resources :users do
  post 'confirm'
end
```

Yuri Barbashov is right, a post make a lot more sense here.

Comment: You might want to check rake routes.